# Can't install Deltachat Node Bot Base

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I tried installing the node package `deltachat-node-bot-base` according to the [instructions](https://github.com/deltachat-bot/deltachat-node-bot-base#installation) but it failed for some reason:

```
$ npm install --save git://github.com/deltachat-bot/deltachat-node-bot-base
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/pixelcode/RemoteBot/node_modules/deltachat-node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node node/scripts/install.js
npm ERR! [i] Building rust core & c bindings, if possible use prebuilds
npm ERR! [i] running `npm run install:prebuilds`
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! > deltachat-node@1.100.0 install:prebuilds
npm ERR! > cd node && node-gyp-build "npm run build:core" "npm run build:bindings:c:postinstall"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! > deltachat-node@1.100.0 build:core
npm ERR! > npm run build:core:rust && npm run build:core:constants
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! > deltachat-node@1.100.0 build:core:rust
npm ERR! > node node/scripts/rebuild-core.js
npm ERR! Could not find cargo
npm ERR! node:child_process:946
npm ERR!     throw err;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: npm run install:prebuilds
npm ERR!     at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:871:11)
npm ERR!     at execSync (node:child_process:943:15)
npm ERR!     at run (/home/pixelcode/RemoteBot/node_modules/deltachat-node/node/scripts/install.js:7:3)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pixelcode/RemoteBot/node_modules/deltachat-node/node/scripts/install.js:16:3)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12) {
npm ERR!   status: 1,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   output: [ null, null, null ],
npm ERR!   pid: 5034,
npm ERR!   stdout: null,
npm ERR!   stderr: null
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Node.js v19.0.1
```

Why is that and how can I fix the error?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement from [Delta Chat](https://chaos.social/@delta/109337001421695240):

> Hi, the base-bot library you are trying to use is outdated and abandoned, the recommended ways to create bots with nodeJS are:
> https://github.com/deltachat-bot/echo/tree/master/nodejs_napi_jsonrpc and https://github.com/deltachat-bot/echo

Answer (score 1):

"Could not find cargo" you need rust if you use want to compile/install it on a platform with no prebuilds: https://rustup.rs

If you tried to install/compile it on a raspberry pi or similar low ram device, then it would make sense to reach out to deltachat developers and ask for an arm prebuild.

There is no nodejs wrapper around this yet, but there are meanwhile prebuilds for the jsonrpc api, as a standalone executable for deltachatcore that exposes the jsonrpc api over stdio:

https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-core-rust/releases/tag/v1.118.0

There is already a wrapper library for using it in python though: https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-core-rust/tree/master/deltachat-rpc-client